# Facebook Messenger API won't send message after 24 hours

Tags: facebook

I have in the past had a successful messaging system that basically exists on my website (Internal with friends). When one of my friends submits the form (Happens multiple times per week) it will inform the friend group via a FB page chat response.

It has been working fine but I think Facebook updated the API and now the chat won't send a message to users that haven't interacted with the chat in 24 hours.

Here is some relevant code:

```
$jsonData = '{
    "messaging_type": "MESSAGE_TAG",
        "recipient":{
            "id":"' . $sender . '"
        },
        "message":{
            "text":"' . $message . '"
        },
        "tag": "ACCOUNT_UPDATE"
 }';
```

[This page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/message-tags) says

> Businesses are encouraged to respond within 24 hours to user’s messages and Message tags enable sending important and personally relevant 1:1 updates to users outside the standard messaging window.
> Does anyone know if any of these tags would help me basically message people infinitely without having them needing to interact every 24 hours? Or is there other options I can play with?

I can of tripped through this dev as it's not my strong suit so I hope everything you need is there.

A second explanation of the messaging system:

- User places a bet with a bookie
- Comes to my site that is only visible to our group of friends
- Submits bet to website through form
- Bet details are written in a facebook message so other people in the group are aware.
- Bet comes through the Facebook page message system

Answer (score 0):

I know Facebook permissions can be super finicky.  When you do a test of this system, can you log the responses from the API calls to see if there is any silent errors.  You may need to poke around in the response headers. Also, if you know which call is failing, see if you can take the call and place it in the [graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) (make sure the Access Tokens are correct).  This may help. I have had a recent issue with the pages API not throwing an error code but just responding with an empty response.  Also, what is the status of this app? Is the app live and if not are the users listed as testers?

Comment: Hey, It's a live app and it will respond with bets for the first 24 hours correctly so I at least know it is working. After the 24 hours though it needs an interaction from people to start a new 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's an old post but that might help someone in the future.

According to this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/message-tags

You can not send a response after 24 hours. Unless it's a registered event.

Therefore, in the basic form of messenger API from [Github](https://github.com/fbsamples/messenger-platform-samples/blob/f7558fe2b0f21b8e5d25a5a18472ccd140f8628c/quick-start/app.js#L177), it has this block of code

```
  let requestBody = {
    'recipient': {
      'id': senderPsid
    },
    'message': response
  };
```

You've to add the event tag, as following:

```
  let requestBody = {
    'recipient': {
      'id': senderPsid
    },
    "message": response,
    "messaging_type": "MESSAGE_TAG",
    "tag": "CONFIRMED_EVENT_UPDATE"
  };
```

That should allow you to send a message after the 24 hours span.

Comment: I tried this and had my app shut down, even though it was in beta mode and was only messaging me debug messages. Apparently this tag is only for updates about events and they have a human reviewing messages to make sure it is only used for this specific use case

Answer (score 0):

I can send the outer twenty-four hour via the Messenger API from the below endpoint:

```java
  String recipientJson = "{\"id\":\"" + customerId + "\"}";
        String requestUrl = facebookUrl  + "/" + pageId + "/messages"
                + "?recipient=" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(recipientJson, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                + "&messaging_type=MESSAGE_TAG"
                + "&message=" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(text, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                + "&tag=" + "CONFIRMED_EVENT_UPDATE"
                + "&access_token=" + token;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).